# Bubbly Flow and two phase flow modelling

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

When we pour vine or some other drink why bubbles move upward and what law they follow or what is the law that describe that motion? 
One other question If we consider a simple two phase flow between two plates or cylinder what numercal method we can use to describe it in MATLAB OR Mathematics.
Thanks

Comment: Air has a lower density than wine so it rises due to [Archimedes' principle of buoyancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle).

Answer (score 0):

The bubbles move upwards because of their density. Since there density is less than that of the liquid, the has inside displaces a weight of liquid greater than its own. This results in an upward buoyant force.